# WinJS.Application.addEventListener vs. WinJS.Application.onActivated

Tags: winjs

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212679.aspx) shows two options for setting up the **onactivated** event for Win8 WinJS apps:

```
WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", listenerName);
```

or

```
WinJS.Application.onactivated = listenerName;
```

Do both options behave identically under the hood, or are there reasons to use one approach over the other?

Comment: I just [read a post](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/winrt/3560-getting-started-with-winrt-javascript.html?start=1) where the author says, "If possible always use addEventListener because it allows you to set multiple event handlers". Can anyone comment whether they've actually needed to do this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same. "onactivated" is the free onFoo event created by the WinJS Event mixin helpers. You can use either with impunity.

I prefer the addEventListener pattern myself.

Comment: Mentioning the bit about mixins helped me understand what makes them synonomous

Answer (score 2):

The `onactivated` style is called "DOM Level 0" because it was not technically part of the DOM, but was rather just the way it evolved to work before the DOM was drawn up. The `addEventListener` method is called the "DOM Level 2" method.
As Dominic said, both are essentially equivalent, but I happen to prefer the `onactivated` style for one reason. I like to use anonymous functions like this...

```
app.onactivated = function(args) {
    ...
};
```

If you use the DOM Level 2 method, however, it's a bad idea to get in the habit of using anonymous functions because you don't get a handle to the function and can thus never remove it. So if you do...

```
app.addEventListener("activated", function(args) {
    ...
});
```

Then you don't have a handle to that function and can't get it removed. You would thus want to define a named function like this...

```
app.addEventListener("activated", myActivatedFunction);
function myActivatedFunction(args) {
    ...
}
```

That way if you ever need to remove the handler you can do...

```
app.removeEventListener("activated", myActivatedFunction);
```

I have an example of this in the Event Handlers demo in my [codeSHOW project](http://codeshow.codeplex.com).

Have fun.

Comment: Nice link to your codeSHOW project! A lot in there for a noob like me to digest.

Comment: You mentioned that a downside of using anonymous functions with the DOM Level 2 method is that you don't get a handle to the function and thus can never remove it. I was wondering if doing `app.onactivated = null` would do the trick?

Comment: Actually, I just tested what I asked in my last comment...and it doesn't work. Setting `onactivated` to null will clear out any previous event handlers set via the DOM Level 0 approach, but won't touch those that are set via the DOM Level 2 approach.

Comment: I created a helper that takes event names, handlers and returns an object with a `.cancel` method. This method adds the listeners, and holds onto the handlers so you can easily clean them up later. Cancel also makes it super short to right rather than lots of removeEventListeners